# Handling Dynamic Xpath Values

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have an **Xpath = .//*[@id='select2-result-label-535']** and 
I used below code to handle the same dynamic values but this is not working:-

```
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {

    String mpath = ".//*[@id='select2-result-label-535']"+i+"']";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(mpath)).click();
    }
```

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong or if there is any other way.

Comment: Typo - you're missing an opening square bracket - `".//*[@id='select2-result-label-535']["+i+"']"`.  Also remember that XPath counts from 1, not 0.

Comment: Do you want the resultant xpath series to look like this: `//*[@id='select2-result-label-535'][1]`, `//*[@id='select2-result-label-535'][2]`, `//*[@id='select2-result-label-535'][3]`,... `//*[@id='select2-result-label-535'][9]` ?

Comment: Actually the xpath mentioned above is for a dropdown which has 3 options so following are the corresponding xpaths :- .//*[@id='select2-result-label-535'], .//*[@id='select2-result-label-536'] , .//*[@id='select2-result-label-537'] but everytime with new session the paths are getting changed e.g. .//*[@id='select2-result-label-643'], .//*[@id='select2-result-label-644'] , .//*[@id='select2-result-label-645']

Comment: can you post the relevent HTML code

Comment: I am putting the HTML code in below 2 comments :-               <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-drop-active" style="left: 1044.5px; width: 200px; top: 103.85px; bottom: auto; display: block;" id="select2-drop">
<div class="select2-search select2-search-hidden select2-offscreen">
<ul id="select2-results-2" class="select2-results" role="listbox">
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable ng-scope ng-binding" role="presentation">
<div id="select2-result-label-194" class="select2-result-label" role="option">

Comment: <span class="select2-match"></span>
compare two transactions
</div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable ng-scope ng-binding select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
<div id="select2-result-label-195" class="select2-result-label" role="option">
<span class="select2-match"></span>
reassign a transaction
</div>
</li>

Comment: <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable ng-scope ng-binding" role="presentation">
<div id="select2-result-label-196" class="select2-result-label" role="option">
<span class="select2-match"></span>
merge two MPIDs
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style="display: block;"></div>

Comment: @Naman : Please edit your question with the above mentioned HTML snippets, rather than adding in the Comments section. It will be wasy to comprehend then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML snippet you've given above, you can try either of the below codes to select an option from the dropdown:

```
    //To click on the dropdown element
    WebElement select_drop = driver.findElement(By.id("select2-drop"));
    select_drop.click();

    //Get all the elements with role attribute as 'option'
    List<WebElement> options = select_drop.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='option']"));
    System.out.println("Number of clickable options in the dropdown: "+options.size());

    //To click on a specific option with certain text/innerHTML like 'reassign a transaction'
    for(WebElement option: options){
        if(option.getText().contains("reassign a transaction")){
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

### [OR]

```
    WebElement select_drop = driver.findElement(By.id("select2-drop"));
    select_drop.click();

    //Get all the elements with role attribute as 'option'
    List<WebElement> options = select_drop.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='option']"));
    System.out.println("Number of clickable options in the dropdown: "+options.size());

    //To click on the first element in the dropdown
    options.get(0).click();

    //To click on the second element in the dropdown
    options.get(1).click();

    //To click on the third element in the dropdown
    options.get(2).click();
```

**Note:-** You can only click the elements from **"0" to "size-1"** for the above code. Beyond that will throw an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**